# Is there a tag that exists that represents multiple declarations?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'd like to use a tag such as `multiple-declarations` for a question that is regarding something like:

```
int a = 0, b = 1;
```

Maybe this tag is too specialized but the question I want to ask is regarding how a compiler reads this.

Can someone add this tag or can someone tell me if there is something else that already exists for this concept?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do fine using the general [declaration](/questions/tagged/declaration), or [variable-declaration](/questions/tagged/variable-declaration). There is no existing tag that seems to denote that concept in itself, but I don't think that it is often enough a crucial part of questions that it needs to be distinguished from the general scenario.